# How can I write more efficient CSS for the max-width

Tags: css

I currently have this code in my wordpress child theme. It allows me to customize the width of individual posts by surrounding the content in a div. While it may not be best practice to have such a variety in page-widths, it is a feature I would like my site to have.

However the list of css classes I'm using to accomplish this task is growing out of control. How can I reduce the length of my code while keeping max-width flexibility?

Specifically, is there a way to assign an entry that will accomplish:

```
div.max($width) {

  max-width: ($width)px;

  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

where $width = the max-width selected?

```
    div.max500 {
      max-width:500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.max600 {
      max-width:600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.max650 {
      max-width:650px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.max700 {
      max-width:700px;
      margin: 0 auto;

    }

    div.max750 {
      max-width:750px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.max800 {
      max-width:800px;
      margin: 0 auto;

    }      

    div.max900 {
      max-width:900px;
      margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, CSS does not have a built-in way to accomplish the kind of dynamic class generation that you're looking for. There's not much benefit of using CSS classes this way, though. You might as well specify the max-width directly on the style attribute of the div, like so:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 500px;"> Content </div>
```

However, you could use a common `container` class in your CSS, which sets the margins, and specifies the default width (most commonly used) and if needed simply override the `max-width` value using the `style` attribute. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```